# How do I solve the object Object error from jQuery/Javascript in Internet Explorer?

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer

Printing to the browser window is the text [object Object] in Internet Explorer whenever I lick on anything that uses jQuery.

This isn't happening with any other browser.

I'm not sure how to solve this and I've Googled answers but didn't understand.

Comment: Don't lick, that's unhygienic - try to click instead. On a more serious note though, can you show us your HTML/jQuery or link to your website?

Comment: Your `doctype` is set on your page? You've really not provided any useful information.

Comment: ;) It's http://poemba.se

Comment: @poembase Have you seen the console warnings in IE10? It may not solve your issue, but you should make sure all your `<scripts>` are inside either the `<head>` or `<body>` tag and not outside. Also you have an extra `"` at the end of this - `"javascript:$('#welcome').toggle();""`